# Flipboard animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

Does anyone knows how to build a flip animation like the flipboard app?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the page flip transition, have a look at the OpenGL transition class I wrote.

https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView

I added a couple of example transitions and one of them are a "page flip" transition.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [FlipView](http://github.com/raweng/FlipView), it tries to replicate Flipboard app for iPad

Some of the features implemented are:

- Multiple flip (just click on last pagination if u r at first or second for multi-flip).
- Views arrangement if orientation changed like Flipboard
- Selection of random layout

Hopefully this link is of some help to you :D

Comment: FlipView link is broken.  Does the project still exist?

Answer (score 6):

I remember from watching an interview with the CEO saying that all the flipping boards and the animations are done using HTML5! I can not find it now sorry :(

I managed to find the non-broken link to FlipView example on github: https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same for weeks. If you use the 'origami' transition in the ipad's photo app, you'll see that it has a very similar flipboard effect. Though someone with much more programming chops can probably give you the specifics, I think they use core animation. In it, you can define the anchor point and basically transform the uiview along the z axis.