# UIView - Animating a view

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I would like to have my UIView opening to one side with the press of a button. I mean just like a door would open, with its side fixed, but not a complete rotation, just to a 30-40° angle. How can I do that? I tried flipping the UIView with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom, but it flips completely and with the axis at its center, not to one side. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO question talks about how to create a page turn animation like the Flipboard iPad app.  You could certainly use this as a starting point to make an animation that only flips part of the way:

[Flipboard animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158108/flipboard-animation)

Comment: Great project, the animations are great, but they are too different from the one I want to use, and so I don't know how to adopt it